# Preparation of shell script

Tags: shell, expect, csh

Recently I have been involved for the preparation of the shell script on SunOS with csh shell. I will have multiple queries but first the short program isn't working.

```
[username]% expect - << EOF  
Spawn telnet 74.125.71.103  
expect "Password:"  
send "google\r"  
EOF
```

The following error pops up:

```
/bin/csh: Event not found  
[username]% expect: Command not found
```

Please advise.

This script should run in following manner :

1. Telent the IP and use the existing passwd (explicitly given in the script).
2. After the telnet, it shows MENU options
3. MB station
4. RC
5. ODU
6. AP
7. SU
8. Exit

> type 1 // a  "MB station" MENU options will open i.e.
>   
>   1 - Show
>   2 - Unit Control
>
> type 2 // UC MENU options will open i.e

1 - Change Password
2 - Reset

> type 1 //change passwd MENU options will open i.e.

1 - Change PC Password
2 - Change LU Password
3 - Change Admin Password

> type 3 // to change ADMIN passwd

MB station - Change Admin Password
Enter New Password                  : XYZ enter
Re-enter Password                   : XYZ enter

New password accepted

3 times escape // to escape from telnet

1.MB station
2. RC
3. ODU
4. AP
5. SU
6. Exit

> type 6        // to exit
>   Exit? [Y/N] y

Connection to host lost.

then move to step with different IP. The IP values will be given by the user one-time while executing the script at the prompt e.g. ./pass-change IPs.txt

Comment: The problem is in the first sentence: `with csh shell`.  Don't use [C Shell](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) for serious programming.

Answer (score 1):

The `Event not found` message implies you're trying to do some kind of history substitution.  This normally involves the `!` character.  Did you type something with a `!` character in it at some point?

And `expect: Command not found` means just what it says: the shell wasn't able to find the `expect` command.  Is it installed?  If not, you should install it if you can, or ask a system administrator to install it for you, or, failing that, [obtain the source](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) and build and install it under your home directory.

Once you fix that, there's an expect command called `spawn`, and it's case-sensitive; `Spawn` won't be recognized.

If you're specifically asking how to accomplish the above *without using `expect`*, please update your question to make that clear.

Comment: ya, I did at the starting of the shell : "#!/bin/csh" as Shebang...Should it be a problem ?  ya, it seems "Expect isn't installed. Then if I have to make a script on SUnOS to call for remote loging (like telnet), how is it possible ? May you pls reframe it for me without expect ?

Comment: @Ashish: No, the `!`in the shebang doesn't invoke the history mechanism.  It's hard to tell what did.  You should be able to install `expect`.  I don't understand what you're trying to do well enough to suggest an alternative.  Try telling us what you're trying to accomplish rather than just what you tried that didn't work.

Comment: The script is about to change the passwd for 10 machines from existing passwd(common for all machines) to new passwd (again should be identical for all machines).

Comment: Can anyone what sort of of shell script can be prepared for the design ?

Comment: @ABeri: A good start would be to address the questions I asked.  Did you type a `!` character (other than the one in `#!/bin/csh`), perhaps as part of your password?  Is `expect` installed on your system?

Comment: the answer to both your questions is "No"

Comment: @ABeri: Given that there's no `!`, I don't know why you would have gotten the `/bin/csh: Event not found` message.  Given that `expect` isn't installed on your system, what the *bleep* do you expect to happen when you try to invoke it?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, I edited my post when you asked "Try telling us what you're trying to accomplish rather than just what you tried that didn't work. "...I prefer you stick to your question and understand my requirement starting from "This script should run...". May be you should read my post and comments above where I have admitted I don't have expect installed. Since I have no rights in the system to install any rpm, so it will be useful if you could draft me an shell script on the basis of my requirement.

Comment: @ABeri: I see.  Your use of `expect` in your sample code when it isn't installed -- and when you don't mention in the question that isn't installed -- is confusing.  If you need `expect`, can you ask an administrator to install it for you?  If not, you should be able to build it from source and install it under your home directory.  If you're trying to find a way to do all this *without using expect*, it would be helpful to say so in your question.  (I don't think I can answer that.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a working script below, you are getting error because i believe you are trying to run the script using some sh or other command. Try to run it as ./script. I used below sample script for file transfer but i did teh key exchange manyally by ssh back and forth which is one time activity. 
    #!/usr/bin/expect -f
    set timeout 130
    spawn ssh "idk@server.com"
    expect "password: "
    send "pass@1234\r"
    expect "$ "
    send "sh /home/nathalok/HTML/run.sh\r"
    expect "$ "
    send "exit\r"

Comment: Ignore the formatting, all code is coming in single line